# How to split a file according to a column (including header) and rename the generated files?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a `.txt` that can be exemplified like this:

```
NAME | CODE
name1 | 001
name2 | 001
name3 | 002
name4 | 003
name5 | 003
name6 | 003
```

I need to write a script to split this file according to the `CODE` column, so in this case I'd get this:

```
file 1:
NAME | CODE
name1 | 001
name2 | 001

file 2:
NAME | CODE
name3 | 002

file 3:
NAME | CODE
name4 | 003
name5 | 003
name6 | 003
```

According to some research, using awk would work:

```
$ awk -F, '{print > $2".txt"}' inputfile
```

The thing is, I also need to include the header to the first line and I need the file names to be different. Instead of `001.txt`, for example, I need the file name to be something like `FILE_$FILENAME_IDK.txt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
awk 'NR==1{h=$0; next}
!seen[$3]++{f="FILE_"FILENAME"_"$3".txt";print h > f} 
{print >> f}' infile
```

The above saves the header in a variable `h` (`NR==1{h=$0; next}`) then, if `$3` not seen (`!seen[$3]++` i.e. if it's the first time it encounters the current value of `$3`) it sets the *filename* (`f=...)` and writes the header to *filename* (`print h > f`). Then it appends the entire line to *filename* (`print >> f`). It uses default `FS` (field separator): *blank*. If you want to use `|` as `FS` (or even a regex with `gnu awk`) see *cas*' comment below.

Comment: This script also produces a file named CODE.txt.
Plus, the file FILE_inputfile_003.txt contents are not quite right:

NAME | CODE
name4 | 003
name5 | 003
NAME | CODE
name6 | 003

It would be nice if you explained a bit your script too =)

Comment: @Kira - yeah, I made a mistake, it should work OK now.

Comment: or, if you want to use `|` as the field separator: `awk -F'|' 'NR==1{h=$0; next} !seen[$2]++{f="FILE_"FILENAME"_"$2".txt";gsub(/ /,"",f);print h > f} {print >> f}'`.  the `gsub()` is to strip the whitespace at the start of field 2, e.g. ` 001` -> `001`

Comment: it should be possible to just use ` | ` as the field separator and not need to use gsub...but i can't figure out how to get awk to treat `|` as a literal char and not a regexp `|`.  if i try `-F' \| '` it just says `warning: escape sequence '\|' treated as plain '|'`

Comment: got it.  `awk -F' \\| ' 'NR==1{h=$0; next} !seen[$2]++{f="FILE_"FILENAME"_"$2".txt";print h > f} {print >> f}'`    thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867060/awk-warning-escape-sequence-treated-as-plain

Comment: that's so counter-intuitive, though.  I read it as escaping the \ itself, but it's a bizarre way of escaping the `|`.

Comment: @cas the FS is a regex that eats the `\ `, you need to escape the `\ ` first and then used the escaped `\ ` to escape the `|`. Not very intuitive, granted.

Comment: @terdon - correct, it's called a [dynamic regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps)

Answer (score 1):

I bet someone is going to come up with a one-liner, but I had to make a script:

```
in='inputfile'
header=$(head -n1 "$in")
codes=($(sed -n 's/.*| \([0-9]\+\)/\1/p' "$in" | uniq ))
for line in "${codes[@]}"; do
    out="file_$i.txt"
    echo "$header" > "$out"
    grep "|.* $line$" "$in" >> "$out"
done
```

Comment: When I execute the script I receive the following error: script.sh: 8: script.sh: i++: not found.

Comment: Are you using bash? Check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, #!/bin/bash

Comment: Now with the `i=$((i+1))` it is working properly?

Comment: It generated only 1 file. The rows are sorted correctly (including the headers), but in the same file.

Comment: My first script had this behaviour because I didn't understand your question well, but after I've edited the script it is producing all the files. Please copy the updated script.

Comment: @kira I think the script is great! It's very readable.  Couple of tips: 1) if you're using `bash` features, it's a good idea to put `#!/bin/bash` at the top, and 2) Not a big deal but you could trim the code a bit if you took out the `cat` and gave the filename directly as a parameter to `sed`.

Comment: Please try your scripts before posting. Your `codes` is a string, not an array, you can't iterate over it.

Comment: @terdon I would recommend you to try it too, because it is working fine here. Maybe our shells differ.

Comment: Well, that one came back and bit me! You're quite right, my apologies. The newlines are making it work despite its being a string. I made a couple of improvements to atone for my mistake and to let me take the downvote back.