# How to split a CSV file per initial column (with headers)?

Tags: shell, text-processing

This is a combination of two other questions ([how to split a file by each line prefix](https://superuser.com/q/783611/2259) and [how to split a file according to a column, including the header](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239636/3645)). I want to go from this content in `input.csv`:

```
id,first,second,third
1,a,b,c
333,b,b,b
1,d,e,f
2,d,e,f
1,c,d,e
333,a,a,a
[more lines in the same format]
```

to this content in `1.csv`:

```
id,first,second,third
1,a,b,c
1,d,e,f
1,c,d,e
```

, this content in `2.csv`:

```
id,first,second,third
2,d,e,f
```

, and this content in `333.csv`:

```
id,first,second,third
333,b,b,b
333,a,a,a
```

, that is:

1. **Put all the lines with ID of *N* into `N.csv`.**
2. **Keep the sequence of lines** as in the original.
3. **Include the header** from the original file in all the output files.

This must also be really fast, so a `while read` loop is *not* going to cut it.

Comment: Could you please tell us what's wrong with applying the solution to the first link here? (And write the headers out first or later.)

Comment: As a general rule (and my answer there is no exception) `awk` is fine if you're working with _simple_ csv files (i.e. there are no delimiters embedded in the fields); if you're dealing with more complex csv files my advice is to use a proper tool (e.g. perl, python etc)

Comment: @Sparhawk Adding content at the top of files is at the very least tedious, especially if you have to do it thousands of times. Automation is best.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, definitely. I simply thought this would be a very common case where shell tools could be a simple solution. I've certainly had to do this several times in different contexts.

Comment: @don_crissti Would you be interested in writing an answer with an example script which handles less regular input?

Comment: @l0b0 - I know some python (and basic perl) but I'm not really familiar with the csv modules available for those languages; when I have to deal with complex csv files at work I use [`csvfix`](https://neilb.bitbucket.io/csvfix/) which does lots and lots of stuff... However, in this particular case (as it doesn't know how to save the header) you would still need to add the header to each piece after splitting with [`file_split`](https://neilb.bitbucket.io/csvfix/manual/csvfix16/file_split.html); I'll ask JJoao if he's willing to post a perl solution

Comment: @l0b0 I'm not familiar with your specific data, but if it's for a known set of numbers, you could firstly write out the headers with a `for` loop, then `>>` into them all. Or do it post-split with a `for` and `cat` loop.

Answer (score 8):

This GNU awk command does the trick:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==1{h=$0; next};!seen[$1]++{f=$1".csv"; print h > f};{f=$1".csv"; print >> f; close(f)}' input.csv
```

Caveat: This will not work if there are escaped commas in the first field. Commas in other fields should work fine.

Explanation:

- `-F ','` (field separator) ensures that `$1` etc. refer to the CSV columns rather than space separated values.
- `NR==1{h=$0; next}` treats the first line specially (`NR==1`), by storing the full header line in a variable `h` (`h=$0`) and skipping the line (`next`).
- `!seen[$1]++{f=$1".csv"; print h > f}` treats the first occurrence of any `$1` specially (`!seen[$1]`) by storing `$1` followed by `.csv` into a filename variable `f` and saving the header to that file (`print h > f`).
- `{f=$1".csv"; print >> f; close(f)}` adds the current line to the file (`print >> f`) and closes the file descriptor (`close(f)`) to avoid keeping it around once processing of all lines with a specific ID is done.

Bonus: If you replace `$1` with another field it should do what you expect: Create a file per unique value in that column with the lines containing that value in the given column.

Comment: There is ```f=$1".csv"``` missing before ```print >> f``` to let it work with unsorted input.

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry to spam you all with another answer)
For many situations, the elegant awk versions presented are perfect.
But there is life outside one-liners -- we often need more:

- add extra code to cope with complex csv files;
- add extra steps for normalization, reformatting, processing.

In the following skeleton, we use a Parser of CSV files.
This time we are avoiding one-ligners and even strictly declare the variables!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Parse::CSV;
my %dict=();

my $c = Parse::CSV->new(file => 'a1.csv');

while ( my $row = $c->fetch ) {                    ## for all records
   $dict{$row->[0]} .=   join(" :: ",@$row)."\n";  ## process and save
}

for my $k (keys %dict){                            ## create the cvs files
   open(F,">","$k.cvs") or die;
   print F $dict{$k};
   close F;
}
```

- The main advantage is that we can deal with more complex csv files;
  this time the csv input can have strings with ";", can include multiline fields (csv specification is complex!):

```
 1111,2,3
 "3,3,3",a,"b, c, and d"
 "a more, complex
        multiline record",3,4
```

- to exemplify a processing step, the field separator was changed to " :: "
- to exemplify extra steps we added some optimization: as we used a dict cache, this script runs 100 times faster than my other solution.

Comment: looks good (can't test it right now); thanks for the effort !

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but just an avoid-scrolling  variant of IObO's excellent answer...

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0; next} {print seen[$1]++ ? $0 : h "\n" $0 >$1 ".csv"}'
```

Comment: Nice solution, but if I understand correctly since you don't close the file descriptor after writing it will keep it open for the duration of the command, possibly running out in case of input with many unique IDs.

Comment: I tested it with 300.000 shufled lines and 100.000 unique Ids with no problems (15 minutes in my 8 year old machine), but I am sure I can get out of ??? (memory /  inodes /disc space) if I increase...

Comment: @don_crissti, and l0b0, I added a new answer following the chalange. I believe you can do it better... Feel free to improve and comment.

Answer (score 0):

old school version using only pipes and no `awk`:

**warning**: *it runs on average slower than above `awk` solutions by a factor of the number of keys in the input file*

```
cut -d , -f 1 input.csv | fgrep -v id | sort | uniq | xargs -n1 sh -c '(head -n1 input.csv && egrep "^${0}," input.csv) > ${0}.csv'
```

which does:

- `cut -d , -f 1 input.csv` splits each line of the file by the `,` char and grab the first column (`-f 1`) to keep only the keys
- `fgrep -v id` skip the header
- `sort | uniq` sort and keep only one of each keys
- `xargs -n1 sh -c '<sub shell>'` for each key execute a sub shell
- `head -n1 input.csv` first part of the sub shell grabs the header of the input file
- then `egrep "^${0}," input.csv` grabs the lines matching the key, *it might not be obvious, but that is a loop over each line, that's why it is slow*
- and `> ${0}.csv` finally writes the output into a file named by the key