# How to split CSV file and create multiple CSV files based on a column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv, split

I have a csv file with the format:

Input.csv:

```
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 00:00:00",80953,3.243183,2.943338,358.0123
"2021-01-03 00:01:00",80954,2.173187,1.990327,344.5851
...
"2021-01-03 23:59:00",80957,4.04172,3.82053,355.5481
"2021-01-04 00:00:00",80955,3.700353,3.593842,346.2665
...
"2021-01-04 23:59:00",80956,3.125094,2.922542,350.9915
"2021-01-05 00:00:00",80957,4.04172,3.82053,355.5481
...
"2021-01-05 23:59:00",80956,3.125094,2.922542,350.9915
etc...
```

The file contains per minute data for multiple days and gets updated every minute.
I would like to write a bash script that creates multiple csv files based on previous day's TIMESTAMP's Column in input.csv as follows:

```
cat 20210103000000.csv
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 00:00:00",80953,3.243183,2.943338,358.0123
```

---

```
cat 20210103000100.csv
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 00:01:00",80954,2.173187,1.990327,344.5851
```

… so forth, up to last minute for that day

```
cat 20210103235900.csv
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 23:59:00",80957,4.04172,3.82053,355.5481
```

If data for a certain time, e.g. "2021-01-03 17:06:00", is missing/does not exist, then the following file must be created:

```
20210103170600.csv:
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 17:06:00",0,0,0,0
```

The solution on this article [How to split a CSV file per initial column (with headers)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343720/how-to-split-a-csv-file-per-initial-column-with-headers)

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==1{h=$0; next};!seen[$1]++{f=$1".csv"; print h > f};{f=$1".csv"; print >> f; close(f)}' input.csv
```

partly solves my problem but it create files for all the data contained in the input.csv file and doesn't take into account missing records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F, -v yesterday="$(date -d'-1day' +'%F')" '
BEGIN{ for(min=0; min<1440; min++){
           mins = "date +%F\" " "\"%T -d\"" min "minutes" yesterday"\""
           mins |getline yday_tmp; close(mins);
           timestamp["\"" yday_tmp "\""] }
     }

NR==1{ hdr=$0; next }

($1 in timestamp){
           cp=$1; gsub(/[-": ]/, "", cp);
           print hdr ORS $0 >(cp".csv");
           close(cp".csv");
           delete timestamp[$1] }

END{ for (x in timestamp){
         cpx=x; gsub(/[-": ]/, "", cpx);
         print hdr ORS x ",0,0,0,0" >(cpx".csv")
         close(cpx".csv")
     }
}' infile
```

---

Using GNU `awk` for the [strftime()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) and [mktime()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) functions to reduce the execution time for generating the timestamps instead of calling external `date` command and also store the files in separate *day* directory and remove all double quotes:

```
gawk -F, '
BEGIN{ start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);
       for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
           timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)]
     }

{ gsub(/"/,"") }

NR==1{ 
       hdr=$0; yday=strftime("dir_%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
               system("mkdir "yday); next 
     }

(substr($1,1,16) in  timestamp){
       cp=$1; gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);
       print hdr ORS $0 >(yday"/"cp".csv");
       close(yday"/"cp".csv");
       delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)] }

END{ for (x in  timestamp){
         cpx=x; gsub(/[-: ]/, "", cpx);
         print hdr ORS x ",0,0,0,0" >(yday"/"cpx".csv");
         close(yday"/"cpx".csv")
     }
}' infile
```

---

As in [GNU `awk` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html):
`systime()` Return  the current time of day as the number of ***seconds*** since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC on POSIX systems).
Let's print it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print systime() }'
1614100199
```

`mktime(timestamp)` Turn the ***timestamp*** in the format of the *`YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`* into the epoch time.

Let's print it;

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print mktime("2021 02 22 00 00 00") }'
1613939400
```

`strftime(format, timestamp)`: Format *timestamp* according to the specification in *format*. The *timestamp* should be
in the epoch type.

Let's format a timestamp:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", mktime("2021 02 23 01 02 00")) }'
2021-02-23 01:02:00
```

---

Remember all 3 above `awk` time functions.

Now let's see what they do one by as used in the answer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print systime()-86400 }'
1614014848
```

Notice the *`86400`* is the number of seconds in each day or 24hours; at above we said `systime()` return current time of day as the number of ***seconds*** since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so if we minus seconds of a day from current time it gives us the time with yesterday date.

Let's convert it to human readable to see what is that:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);  }'
2021 02 22 00 00 00
```

now it's clear what timestamp it is, we used Hour/Min/Sec to "00" because we need this timestamp as start point and we store it into `start` variable in the code.

then we used a for-loop to generate the rest of the timestamps from the timestamp in the `start` variable as following:

```
for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
    timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)]
```

Notice the number `1440`? that is the number of minutes in  a day or 24hours (24*60=1440); but `mktime()` accept timestamp as epoch and in seconds, so we multiply each minute to 60 to get timestamps in seconds then turn it into this format `%F %H:%M` (`F`ull format of the date same as `%Y-%m-%d`, `H`our and `M`inute) and save into an *awk* array we name it `timestamp[...]`; now we have yesterday's date of all timestamps minutely.

you can even print them to see what they are:

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN{
         start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);
         for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
             timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)];
         for (t in timestamp)
             print t
  }'
```

Below [gsub()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1) function removes all quotes from the current line:

```
{ gsub(/"/,"") }
```

then we backup the input file's first line which is the header line into `hdr` variable as we need the header line to be added into every file we generate; then also we create a directory with yesterday date as well and it will take the format of `dir_%Y%m%d`; below code block runs once only when it's first input line `NR==1 { "run these" }`:

```
NR==1{ 
       hdr=$0; yday=strftime("dir_%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
       system("mkdir "yday); next 
}
```

With the [system()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function) function we are calling the external command `mkdir` to create that directory.

Going into next block, run the following block only if timestamp from the first column was seen in the *`timestamp`* array *`(substr($1,1,16) in timestamp) { "run these" }`*; [substr(string, start [, length ])](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function) function return a ***length***-character-long substring of ***string***, starting at character number ***start***.

- `cp=$1`: we copy first column into `cp` variable, we will use value in the `cp` for later processing.
- `gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);`; strip characters `-`, `:` and Space from the `cp` variable as well as the trailing double zero "00"s.
- `print hdr ORS $0 >(yday"/"cp".csv");`: `print` the header line which we keep it in the `hdr` var, an `ORS` (that's a newline character for ***O***utput ***R***ecord ***S***eparator by default) and entire line `$0` into the related `directory/fileName.csv`.
- `close(yday"/"cp".csv");`: [close()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html#index-close_0028_0029-function) the file after write.
- `delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)]`: and delete that timestamp from the array.

and in the `END { "run these" }` block we print to the files for those timestamps that didn't exist in the input file.

---

To process multiple files and split each input file into individual *day* directory.

```
gawk -F, '
{ gsub(/"/,"") }

FNR==1{
       delete timestamp;
       start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);
       for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
           timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)]
       hdr=$0; yday=strftime("%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
       fname=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"", fname); dirName=fname"_"yday;
       system("mkdir "dirName); next
     }

(substr($1,1,16) in  timestamp){
       cp=$1; gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);
       print hdr ORS $0 >(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       close(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)] }

ENDFILE{ for (x in  timestamp){
             cpx=x; gsub(/[-: ]/, "", cpx);
             print hdr ORS x ",0,0,0,0" >(dirName"/"cpx".csv");
             close(dirName"/"cpx".csv")
     }
}' multiple*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force approach, to fill in the gaps from your existing solution: it tests 1440 files, but, hey, it's only once a day, and it's yesterday date. In Bash:

(a) Get yesterday's date in both formats: `dt=20210103` and `2021-01-03`.

(b) Run a `for` loop: `for hm in {00..23}{00..59`}.

(c) For any file `${dt}${hm}00.csv` not present: printf the required header and detail line into it.

I assume the split part you posted works, and you only need to fill in the gaps in the timestamps.

This Bash solution is tested and commented. It runs in under a second.

```
#! /bin/bash

#.. In the current directory, this script makes dummy files such that:
#.. (a) There shall be a file for every minute in the previous day.
#..     with the name like YYYYmmddHHMM00 (e.g. 20210103173800.csv).
#.. (b) Any existing file with that name shall not be affected in any way.
#.. (c) Any new file shall contain a header line and one data line, like:
#..     TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
#..     "2021-01-03 17:38:00",0,0,0,0

#.. Create all the data apart from the hh,mm values.
fnYest="$( date -d '- 1 day' '+%Y%m%d%%s%%s00.csv' )"
dtYest="$( date -d '- 1 day' '+"%Y-%m-%d %%s:%%s:00"' )"
Header='TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4'
Fields=',0,0,0,0'

#.. These five lines are debug, and can be removed.
printf 1>&2 'fnYest: %s\n' "${fnYest}"
printf 1>&2 'dtYest: %s\n' "${dtYest}"
printf 1>&2 "Filename:  ${fnYest}\n" 13 58
printf 1>&2 "TimeStamp: ${dtYest}\n" 13 58
printf 1>&2 "Line 1: %s\nLine 2: ${dtYest}%s\n" "${Header}" 13 58 "${Fields}"

#.. Creates the files that are missing.

for hh in {00..23}; do
    for mm in {00..59}; do
        printf -v fn "${fnYest}" "${hh}" "${mm}" 
        [[ -r "${fn}" ]] && continue
        printf > "${fn}" "%s\n${dtYest}%s\n" "${Header}" "${hh}" "${mm}" "${Fields}"
    done
done
```