# How to create folders based on part of a filename and also extract & rename specific columns using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

the following code extracts data from csv files contained in a folder, creates new folders (based on filename and date), creates and stores multiple csv files in the said folders. more info on this is here [how-to-split-csv-file-and-create-multiple-csv-files-based-on-a-column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635715/how-to-split-csv-file-and-create-multiple-csv-files-based-on-a-column/635803#635803).

```
gawk -F, '
BEGIN{ start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);
       for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
           timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)]
     }

{ gsub(/"/,"") }

FNR==1{
       hdr=$0; yday=strftime("%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
       fname=FILENAME; sub(/.csv$/,"", fname); dirName=fname"_"yday;
       system("mkdir "dirName); next
     }

(substr($1,1,16) in  timestamp){
       cp=$1; gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);
       print hdr ORS $0 >(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       close(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)] }

ENDFILE{ for (x in  timestamp){
             cpx=x; gsub(/[-: ]/, "", cpx);
             print hdr ORS x ",0,0,0,0" >(dirName"/"cpx".csv");
             close(dirName"/"cpx".csv")
     }
}' multiple*.csv
```

1. how can I use part of a filename to create a folder (within awk) e.g. filename is `Thaban_TD_xxxxxx_Forms1.csv` and want to create a folder named `xxxxxx_date`. In its current form, the code above create folders with names based on full csv file name. the length of `xxxxxx` varies but the file name format is always the same.
2. I'd also like to extract Timestamp, Data2, Data4 columns, rename 'Data2' to 'Info' and 'Data4' to 'Output', and then round off data in Info and Output columns to 3 decimal digits. in the same code

input file: `Thaban_TD_xxxxxx_Forms1.csv`

```
TIMESTAMP,Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4
"2021-01-03 00:00:00",80953,3.243183,2.943338,358.0123
"2021-01-03 00:01:00",80954,2.173187,1.990327,344.5851
...
"2021-01-03 23:59:00",80957,4.04172,3.82053,355.5481
"2021-01-04 00:00:00",80955,3.700353,3.593842,346.2665
...
"2021-01-04 23:59:00",80956,3.125094,2.922542,350.9915
"2021-01-05 00:00:00",80957,4.04172,3.82053,355.5481
...
"2021-01-05 23:59:00",80956,3.125094,2.922542,350.9915
etc...
```

This is how I'd like my output to be

Output file `202101030000.csv` inside created folder `xxxxxx_20210103`

```
TIMESTAMP,Info,Output
2021-01-03 00:00:00,3.243,358.012
```

...

Output file `202101032359.csv` inside created folder `xxxxxx_20210103`

```
TIMESTAMP,Info,Output
2021-01-03 23:59:00,4.042,355.548
```

Comment: You can use `sub` or `gsub` to remove unwanted parts, e.g. `Thaban_TD_`, from the file name in a similar way as you remove `.csv`. To me it is not clear how the second question is related to the code. I suggest to [edit] your question and show some example input, the corresponding actual output and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. question updated.

Comment: Please also show the actual output. Can you have more than  one line with the same timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gawk -F, '
{ gsub(/"/,"") }

FNR==1{
       delete timestamp;
       start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-86400);
       for(min=0; min<1440; min++)
           timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)]
       $3="Info"; $5="Output"; hdr=$1 FS $3 FS $5; 
       yday=strftime("%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
       fname=FILENAME; gsub(/Thaban_TD_|_.*\.csv$/,"", fname); dirName=fname"_"yday;
       system("mkdir "dirName); next
     }

(substr($1,1,16) in  timestamp){
       cp=$1; gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);
       printf("%s%s,%.3f,%.3f\n", hdr ORS, $1, $3, $5)>(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       close(dirName"/"cp".csv");
       delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)] }

ENDFILE{ for (x in  timestamp){
             cpx=x; gsub(/[-: ]/, "", cpx);
             print hdr ORS x ",0,0" >(dirName"/"cpx".csv");
             close(dirName"/"cpx".csv")
     }
}' multiple*.csv
```

Things we updated here are as following:

- Updated `gsub(/Thaban_TD_|_.*\.csv$/,"", fname)`

  to remove `Thaban_TD_` and `_<anything>.csv` parts from the fileName
- Added `$3="Info"; $5="Output"`

  to rename the column#3 to `Info` and column#5 to `Output` for the first line only (`NR==1`)
- Updated `hdr=$1 FS $3 FS $5`

  for header-line we only need columns #1, #3 and #5 (`FS` is the `F`ield `S`eparator and that is what we defined in `-F,`)
- Updated `printf("%s%s,%.3f,%.3f\n", hdr ORS, $1, $3, $5)`

  to output columns#3 and #5 with 3 decimal points `%.3f`.
- Updated `print hdr ORS x ",0,0"`

  reduce to output only 3 columns.