# Create new CSV files based on latest timestamp data

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv

I have a script that accesses multiple dat files and produce csv files based on previous day’s data. these DAT files are updated on per minute bases with data from various instruments.

Script snippet:

```
gawk -F, '

{ gsub(/"/,"") }

FNR==2{ 
        delete timestamp;                                     #This code was added
        start=strftime("%Y %m %d 00 00 00", systime()-172800);#to fix the
        for(min=0; min<1440; min++)                           #timestamp formatting
        timestamp[strftime("%F %H:%M", mktime(start)+min*60)] #issue from the input files.
     
        fname=FILENAME; 
        gsub(/Real_|_Table2.*\.dat$/,"", fname);

        $2="col1";
        $3="col2";
        $4="col3";
        $5="col4";
        
        if ( fname=="file1")        ID1="01";   
        else if ( fname=="file2")   ID1="02";
        else if ( fname=="file3")   ID1="03";
        else ID1="00";      
    
        hdr=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5;
         
        yday=strftime("%Y%m%d", systime()-86400);
        dirName=yday;
        system("mkdir -p "dirName); next
     }

(substr($1,1,16) in  timestamp){

        fname=FILENAME; 
        gsub(/Real_|_Table2.*\.dat$/,"", fname);

               cp=$1; gsub(/[-: ]|00$/, "", cp);
         if ( fname=="file2"|| fname=="file3")

         printf("%s%s,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f\n", hdr ORS, $1, $3, $2, $4, $6)>(dirName"/"ID1"_"fname"_"cp".csv");
        else 
        printf("%s%s,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f\n", hdr ORS, $1, $3, $5, "999")>(dirName"/"ID1"_"fname"_"cp".csv");

       close(dirName"/"ID1"_"fname"_"cp".csv");
       delete  timestamp[substr($1,1,16)] }

ENDFILE{ for (x in  timestamp){
             cpx=x; gsub(/[-: ]/, "", cpx);
             print hdr ORS x "-999,-999,-999,-999," >(dirName"/"ID1"_"fname"_"cpx".csv");
             
             close(dirName"/"ID1"_"fname"_"cpx".csv")
     }
}' *_Table2.dat
```

I would like the script to be edited so that it can scan dat files for new data and create a csv files for new data only. in its current format, the script creates csv file for each timestamp in the *.dat files (new or historic).

Sample input file (*Real_file1_table2.dat*):

```
"Data for Site1"
TIMESTAMP,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:00:00",289233,0.3495333,0.2412115,333.2676
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",289234,1.035533,1.019842,344.1969
```

**notice that the header is on line number 2**
Then the following output files are created:

*01_file1_202311301100.csv*

*01_file1_202311301101.csv*

etc..

Data contained in the csv files is based on timestamp..

for example:

*01_file1_202311301100.csv* contains the following data:

```
TIMESTAMP,col1,col2,col3,col4
2023/11/30 11:00,289233,0.349,0.241,333.267
```

*01_file1_202311301101.csv* contains the following data:

```
TIMESTAMP,col1,col2,col3,col4
2023/11/30 11:01,289234,1.035,1.019,344.196
```

etc.

**Take note that data in these csv files is rounded off to 3 floating points**

When executing the script for the 2nd time, the following data is now contained in *Real_file1_table2.dat*:

```
"Data for Site1"
TIMESTAMP,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:00:00",289233,0.3495333,0.2412115,333.2676
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",289234,1.035533,1.019842,344.1969
"2023-11-30 11:02:00",289235,0.7758334,0.7252186,17.75404
"2023-11-30 11:03:00",289236,0.7693,0.7103683,359.0702
```

I’d like the script to create csv files for the latest data only, i.e.:

*01_file1_202311301102.csv*

*01_file1_202311301103.csv*

I don't want csv files that already exist be recreated.

So whenever the script is executed, it must only create csv files for the latest data.

Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Won't the script already do this? If the input file has changed, why would it create csv files for dates that are no longer in the input file? Or, if they are, won't the be the same data so it doesn't matter if the file is created again?

Comment: @terdon, the files in question are huge, with lots of historic data. that is why i only want it to create files based on the latest data only so that processing time can be shortened. if i have to recreate every file, it's going to take forever to complete.

Comment: please update the question to show the contents of the 4x `*.csv` files

Comment: the sample input file shows field #1 (date/time) wrapped in double quotes; is this the only field that will ever be wrapped in double quotes? could field #1 ever contain anything other than a date/time? do any of the fields contain embedded linefeeds?

Comment: for an output file name (eg, `01_file1_202311301100.csv`) ... does the `'file1'` come from `Real_file1_table2.dat`? where does the leading `'01'` come from?

Comment: curent code includes this line: `hdr=$1 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6` which seems to imply there are 6 fields of input, with the 2nd field being ignored (not printed), but the sample input file only contains 5 fields; does the actual input file contain 5 or 6+ fields? if the file contains 6+ fields then please update the question to show complete lines

Comment: @markp-fuso, i had all the information you need to help me but EdMorton told me to edit it as per his comment above... i can put back all the information if needed..

Comment: @EdMorton, please have a look at [how-to-create-folders-based-on-part-of-a-filename-and-also-extract-rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636194/how-to-create-folders-based-on-part-of-a-filename-and-also-extract-rename-spec?noredirect=1#comment1191748_636194). everything is explained there. how all this started. i will add more info to this post just now. thank you for your help

Comment: @markp-fuso, i've added original code for clarity.

Comment: yet another update: input shows a header (FNR==2) value of `Timestamp` in field #1 but the expected output shows `TIMESTAMP` (all caps) ... are suppose to convert field #1 to all caps? you've stated that (fields #3/#4/#5) are to be ***rounded*** to 3 digits, but the output from `01_file1_202311301101.csv` is showing the values have been truncated, ie, for `1.035533` a rounded value would be `1.036` while a truncated value would be `1.035` ... please confirm the requirement (round vs truncate) and update the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- for an output file named `01_file1_202311301100.csv` the string `'file1'` comes from the 2nd '_' delimited field in the input file's name (eg, `Real_file1_table2.dat`)
- OP's code appears to create a new subdirectory for 'yesterday' but would then imply that we're not supposed to process input file entries with a date of 'today'; for the sake of this answer I'm going to assume all input/output files reside in the current directory; OP can expand the code to address subdirectories and how to handle 'yesterday' vs 'today'
- the only input field wrapped in double quotes is the 1st (comma delimited) field
- the 1st field will always be of the format `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"`, otherwise we ignore the line
- no input fields contain embedded newlines

General design:

- in `bash` determine the prefix (`pfx`) of our output files (based on the name of the input file)
- in `bash` determine the name of the 'last' output file
- pass `pfx` and 'last' output file name to `awk`
- use `awk` to process the input `*.dat` file
- build an output filename based on the contents of the 1st field (eg, `2023-11-30 11:00:00` becomes `202311301100`)
- if the output file name is ***less than*** the 'last' output file name then this tells us the output file already exists and so we will ignore the input line
- in the case where the output file name is ***equal to*** the 'last' output file name we will go ahead and generate a new output file (this should address the case where a datetime value - eg: `2023-11-30 11:00` - is added to the `*.dat` file before and after a run of the `awk` script
- in the case where the output file name is ***greater than*** the 'last' output file name then this tells us we need to generate a new output file

One `bash / awk` approach:

```
for datfile in *_table2.dat
do
    [[ ! -f "${datfile}" ]] && break

    ############
    #### the following bash code needs to be run before each run of the awk script

    IFS='_' read -r _ pfx _ <<< "${datfile}"

    case "${pfx}" in
        file1)  pfx="01_${pfx}" ;;
        file2)  pfx="02_${pfx}" ;;    
        file3)  pfx="03_${pfx}" ;;
            *)  pfx="00_${pfx}" ;;
    esac

    last_file="${pfx}_000000000000.csv"

    for outfile in "${pfx}"_*.csv
    do
        [[ -f "${outfile}" ]] && last_file="${outfile}"
    done

    ############
    #### at this point we have:
    ####   1) the '##_file#' prefix for our new output files(s)
    ####   2) the name of the 'last' output file

    awk -v pfx="${pfx}" -v last_file="${last_file}" '
    BEGIN      { FS=OFS=","
                 regex = "^\"[0-9]{4}.*\"$"                               # 1st field regex: "YYYY..."
               }

    FNR==2     { hdr = $0 }

    $1 ~ regex { dt = $1                                                    # copy 1st field
                 gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",dt)                               # strip out everything other than digits
                 dt = substr(dt,1,12)                                     # grab YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM which now looks like YYYYMMDDHHMM

                 if ( dt != dt_prev ) {                                   # if this is a new dt value
                    dt_prev = dt
                    printme = 1                                           # default to printing input lines to new output file

                    close(outfile)                                        # close previous output file
                    outfile = pfx "_" dt ".csv"                           # build new output file name

                    if ( outfile < last_file ) {                          # if "less than" last file then we will skip
                       printf "WARNING: file exists: %s (skipping)\n", outfile
                       printme = 0
                    }
                    else
                    if ( outfile == last_file ) {                         # if "equal to" last file then overwrite
                       printf "WARNING: file exists: %s (overwriting)\n", outfile
                       print hdr > outfile                                # print default header to our overwrite file
                    }
                    else                                                  # else new output file is "greater than" last file
                       print hdr > outfile                                # print default header to our new output file
                 }

                 if ( printme ) {                                         # if printme==1 then print current line to outfile
                    print $1,$2,sprintf("%0.3f%s%0.3f%s%0.3f",$3,OFS,$4,OFS,$5) > outfile
                 }
               }
    ' "${datfile}"
done
```

Running against OP's 1st version of `Real_file1_table2.dat`:

```
$ awk ....

$ head 01*csv
==> 01_file1_202311301100.csv <==
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:00:00",289233,0.3495333,0.2412115,333.2676

==> 01_file1_202311301101.csv <==
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",289234,1.035533,1.019842,344.1969
```

To test the 'overwrite' logic we'll change OP's 2nd version of `Real_file1_table2.dat` as follows:

```
$ cat Real_file1_table2.2.dat
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:00:00",289233,0.3495333,0.2412115,333.2676
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",289234,1.035533,1.019842,344.1969
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",666666,0.7777777,0.8888888,17.99999    # another 2023-11-30 11:01 entry
"2023-11-30 11:02:00",289235,0.7758334,0.7252186,17.75404
"2023-11-30 11:03:00",289236,0.7693,0.7103683,359.0702
```

Running against this new version of `Real_file1_table2.dat`:

```
$ awk ...
WARNING: file exists: 01_file1_202311301100.csv (skipping)
WARNING: file exists: 01_file1_202311301101.csv (overwriting)

$ head 01*csv
==> 01_file1_202311301100.csv <==
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:00:00",289233,0.3495333,0.2412115,333.2676

==> 01_file1_202311301101.csv <==
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",289234,1.035533,1.019842,344.1969
"2023-11-30 11:01:00",666666,0.7777777,0.8888888,17.99999

==> 01_file1_202311301102.csv <==
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:02:00",289235,0.7758334,0.7252186,17.75404

==> 01_file1_202311301103.csv <==
Timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
"2023-11-30 11:03:00",289236,0.7693,0.7103683,359.0702
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain this to me. im going to give it a try in a moment.. please explain something to me.. shouldn't the `last_file` be dynamic? i mean it changes with every script execution, right?

Comment: `last_file` is somewhat dynamic as you need to run the 2x `bash` commands (`last_file=...`, `for outfile in ...`) prior to each run of the `awk` script; I've updated the `bash` portion to insure we're looking for `01_file1_*.csv` files when the input file name contains `_file1_`; you'll need to expand this to address other input file names that contain something other than `_file1_`

Comment: @dante_t added more `bash` code to process multilpe `*_table2.dat` files as well as the logic to determine the prefix of the output file name (ie, `file{1..3}` => `ID=0{1..3}_file{1..3}` )

Comment: sorry for the late response thank you very much for your help. My original code was actually taking into account that the header in *dat* files is on line 2, hence `FNR==2`. also please have a look at floating points in *Real_file1_Table.dat* vs that of *01_file1_202311301100.csv*. These edits should complete my request.

Comment: @dante_t answer has been updated, again but there are inconsistencies in your latest update; is `Timestamp` supposed to be modified to all caps `TIMESTAMP`? do you want values *rounded* or *truncated* to 3 digits? lastest update to the answer leaves `Timestamp` as is and performs *rounding* to 3 digits

Comment: if you have additional changes I would suggest a) try modifying the code to accomplish the latest change in requirements and if still having issues then b) ask a new question while making sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that focuses on the specific technical/coding issue

Comment: i have changed `"Timestamp" to "TIMESTAMP"`. I need the values to be rounded off to 3 decimal places... I will edit the code as per your suggestion and see if i come right. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: the code only works when the prefix is *00*. Also, when running the code for the 2nd time, the recreated file (previous last file) doesn't have a header, it only has data on the first row. I tried to fiddle around with your code but i'm not winning.

Comment: the answer has been updated to address the header issue for an overwrite/rewrite (just had to add a `print hdr` to the `if ( outfile == last_file )` section); as for the `00` prefix issue ... if you're saying that all output files are generated with a `00` prefix then it sounds like your input file names do not match the naming format as listed in the question which would show up as `pfx` not being one of `file{123}` when going into the `case` statement (add `echo "pfx(before)=${pfx}"` before the `case` and `echo "pfx(after)=${pfx}"` after the `case`)

Comment: perhaps my comment is not clear.. 1. the code does generate csv files for *file1*, *file2* & *file3* on the 1st run, but when it is ran for the 2nd time, with new data added to all *dat* files, it does nothing (no new csv files produced)... 2. I added a file called *Real_live_data_table2.dat* to input files. when code is executed, it returns files with *00* prefix. when i add extra data to *Real_live_data_table2.dat*, *csv* files for extra data are produced. hence i said the code only works for *00* prefix... 3. If i want the new input file to work, can't i just add it to the case statement?

Comment: Update: new *csv* files for *Real_file3_table2.dat* are generated but the recreated file (previous last file) still has no header. For *Real_file1_table2.dat* & *Real_file2_table2.dat* files, last *csv* files are recreated with no header, but no new files from new data.

Comment: yes, if you have a new file prefix you should be able to just update the `case` statement; re: the missing hdr in overwrite files ... I've got too many versions of this script on my system and during my previous update I inadvertently cut-n-pasted from the wrong 'up-to-date' script with net result being I actually missed the overwrite/hdr code ... I've now added that into the answer, ie, overwrite/hdr should work now

Comment: re: new data not added to csv files for file{1..3} ... I'm unable to reproduce this issue (ie, script works as expected); the code is written with the assumption that for a given prefix (eg, `file1`) there is only one `*.dat` file; if you can have more than one `*.dat` file for a given prefix then that becomes a more complicated issue especially if new data can be written to all `*.dat` files ... that would require a complete rethink/rewrite of the `bash` code along with changes to `awk` ... so that would effectlively be a new question

Comment: your last update actually fixed everything. the code works as it should. Thank you for taking time to help solve my problem.

Comment: @mark-fuso, last question... where can i update the script so that timestamp is in this format `yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm` ? i just want to replace the '-' with '/'

Comment: have you tried running the script against your new date format? the script should work as is (ie, no need to modify the script); the 3x lines of interest - `dt=$1; gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",dt); dt = substr(dt,1,12)` - reduces (a copy of) the 1st field to just numbers (ie, it strips out spaces, hyphens, colons ... and forward/backward slashes)