# find and replace specific string in multiple csv files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have multiple csv files and the contents are in the following format:

```
"TIMESTAMP",col2,col3,col4
"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm",20,19,17
```

I want to replace `-` with `/` so that in the end I have:

```
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col4
yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm,20,19,17
```

I used the following command to append the files but nothing is happening:

```
find -name '*.csv' -exec awk '{gsub(/-/, "/",$1)}' '{}' \;
```

What am I missing? please help

Comment: Using `\;` at the end of the `find` command makes `find` call `awk` once per file. If you use `+` instead then `find` will call `awk` with multiple files at a time thereby making the whole thing execute much faster.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you Ed

Comment: But...does "`-`" hyphen appear anywhere else in the csv file? Regarding your proposed `awk` solution, wouldn't you want a more specific Regex?

Comment: The tool [`miller` (aka `mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) is good for stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `awk` command does actually make the change you want (except it does it in the first whitespace delimited field instead of comma-delimited), but it doesn't print it since you didn't tell it to print:

```
$ cat  file.csv
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col-4
yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm,20,19,17
$ awk '{gsub(/-/, "/",$1)}' file.csv 
$
```

As you can see above, your command has no output. Compare with:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/-/, "/", $1); print}' file.csv 
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col-4
yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm,20,19,17
```

However, this is unlikely to be what you want since that would just print the contents of all the files to standard output. If you want to modify the actual files, try this instead:

```
$ perl -i -F, -lane '$F[0] =~ s|-|/|g; print join ",",@F' file.csv 
$ cat file.csv
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col4
yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm,20,19,17
```

I suggest you use `-i.bak` which will create a copy of the original file with the extension `.bak`, just in case. Then, you can incorporate this into your command like so:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -type f -exec perl -i.bak -F, -lane '
  $F[0] =~ y|-|/|; print join ",", @F' '{}' +
```

Alternatively, if you have GNU awk (`gawk`) and you can guarantee the current working directory doesn't contain a file called `infile` or `infile.awk`, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -type f -exec gawk -F, -v OFS=, -i inplace '
  {gsub(/-/, "/",$1); print}' '{}' +
```

Comment: thank you 1. The perl solution you gave, changes my timestamp to `yyyy/mm/dd, HH:mm:00` . 2. The `gawk` solution modifies the file with the same character i want to remove, i.e `-` to `-` . I'm saying this because the modification time on the files changes to the current time

Comment: Whoops, sorry @dante_t, I hadn't set the field separator to `,` in the perl one. Fixed now.  I don't know what you mean about the `gawk` one though, it is replacing `-` with `/` not `-` with `-`.

Comment: thank you. i see what the problem is now.. My timestamp is in this format `""yyyy/mm/dd""` and when csv file is opened in excel, the inverted commas are not showing.. i don't want them too.. I'll update my question.. please have look.

Comment: @dante_t that's a whole different thing. Are you now saying you want to remove quotes from all your quoted csv entries? Why? Quoting is important in csv files, for instance, what if you have a field spanning multiple lines? Why don't you just export the file as tsv or csv and tell excel not to quote?

Comment: my csv files actually have 2 line only, the header line and the data line.. the system im uploading these csv files doesnt accept quotes and dashes on the timestamp.

Comment: If your timestamp is in the format `""yyyy/mm/dd""` then it's not valid CSV (it has to be `"""yyyy/mm/dd"""` or `yyyy/mm/dd` to be valid) and so YMMV trying to use tools that understand CSV on it. I don't think any of the answers are trying to process it as CSV, just plain text, so it'll probably be OK for this case but you should try to get whatever is producing that file fixed to output valid CSV. What you refer to as "inverted commas" are "double quotes".

Comment: Solution to my question: `find -name '*.csv' -exec gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/"/,"");gsub("-","/"); print}' '{}' \;` - thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name '*.csv' -type f -size +10c -exec perl -pi -e '
  s{^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\b}{$1/$2/$3}' {} +
```

Would only replace the `-`s in those time stamps at the start of the line and leave all other `-` occurrences alone.

Note that it replaces all `.csv` files even those that don't contain any such timestamp. To avoid that, with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -rlPZ --include='*.csv' '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\b' . |
  xargs -r0 perl -pi -e '
  s{^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\b}{$1/$2/$3}' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Merging the sample input and expected output shown in your question with what you said in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764887/find-and-replace-specific-string-in-multiple-csv-files#comment1458516_764891) about what the timestamp value really looks like:

```
$ cat foo.csv
"TIMESTAMP",col2,col3,col4
""yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm"",20,19,17
```

then using GNU awk for `-i inplace`:

```
$ find . -name 'foo.csv' -exec awk -i inplace '{gsub(/"/,""); gsub(/-/,"/"); print}' {} +

$ cat foo.csv
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col4
yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm,20,19,17
```

or you could replace the GNU awk script with this GNU sed script (for `-i`):

```
sed -i 's:"::g; s:-:/:g'
```

If there can be `"`s or `-`s anywhere else that you do not want replaced and you don't have any `"`s, `,`s or newlines inside quoted fields then change the awk script to:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/"/,"",$1); gsub(/-/,"/",$1); print}
```

Comment: i actually managed to figure it out today.. Thank you :)

Comment: since you are here, i might as well ask you.. would it be possible to do this when csv files in this post [create-new-csv-files-based-on-latest-timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762885/create-new-csv-files-based-on-latest-timestamp-data?noredirect=1#comment1455638_762885) are generated? it would actually save processing time.

Comment: Yes, it'd be trivial. Ask a new question about that if, after attempting it, you can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I actually tried, i couldn't figure it out. hence i came up with this solution.

Comment: Writing a tool to create files with characters and then writing another tool to remove those characters is obviously a bad idea, as I'm sure you know. If you had added the other expected output files to your previous question as I had asked for repeatedly in the comments, and not just accepted the one answer you got which didn't do what you wanted instead, then you'd certainly have gotten an answer to your previous question that produced the output you wanted. Ask a new question and this time include at least 2 input files and the full set of expected output files if you'd like help.

Comment: The thing is, I was using excel to view my csv files, i was not aware that it was hiding characters, I only noticed today when I viewed the files in Notepad++. I'm sorry for taking your comments in a wrong way..

Comment: No problem, I understand. Until you've answered a lot of questions it can be hard to know what makes a good question and why the people trying to help you are asking for so many details but without all those details it's so easy to provide a wrong answer that looks like it's doing the right thing (and then potentially fails 6 months later on your customers real data!).

Comment: Now i don't know how I'm going to ask the question without actually posting that whole script again... can't I just add quotes on my original question and remove them on my expected output?... I don't know really.

Comment: No, you shouldn't significantly change a question after you got answers, and you shouldn't change a question at all after you accepted an answer to it.

Comment: That's what i thought too.. lesson learnt. Thank you Ed!

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*The simplistic way:*

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g{  \w**4  <( (\-)  (\w**2)  (\-) )>  \w**2 } = "/$1/";'  file
```

*Validating CSV content:*

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",");   \
                        @a>>.[0] = @a>>.[0].map:               \
                        *.subst(:global, / \w**4 <( (\-) (\w**2) (\-) )> \w**2 /, {"/$1/"} );  \
                        csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep => ",");'  < file
```

Here are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The first answer uses the familiar `s///` substitution idiom, except here Raku has added a new formatting option: `s{original} = "replacement"`. A match is sought for the correct combination of characters/digits and dashes (hyphens), Raku's `<(…)>` capture markers are used to drop everything outside the desired chunk, which is altered in the replacement.

The second answer validates CSV input/output, using Raku's `Text::CSV` module. Using the example data, only ***the first column*** gets substituted ( the `@a>>.[0]` idiom  specifically addresses the first column of data).

Sample Input:

```
"TIMESTAMP",col2,col3,col4
"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm",20,19,17
```

Sample Output (first code example):

```
"TIMESTAMP",col2,col3,col4
"yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm",20,19,17
```

Sample Output (second code example, validating CSV output):

```
TIMESTAMP,col2,col3,col4
"yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm",20,19,17
```

Raku's `Text::CSV` modules has various options for quoting output columns if you need to change this (the default is to quote column-wise elements containing whitespace). You can also take input within the body of the code, without relying on shell-globbing. Simply change the `csv(in => $*IN, sep => ",");` portion of the code to:

`csv(in => "path/to/file", sep => ",");`

---

https://raku.land/zef:Tux/Text::CSV
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://raku.org