# Command to Sort by second column and Omit first two rows

Tags: linux, sort

I have a CSV file `filename.csv` with the contents.

```
,"Range 1 (%)","Range 2 (%)"
"Color","Number Color 1","Number Color 2"
"Red","99.0","5.2"
"Orange","12.9","0.0"
"Yellow","33.9","1.2"
"Green","13.9","76.2"
"Blue","87.6","97.2"
"Purple","86.8","55.5"
```

I am trying to sort the file numerically by values from the second column. However, the first two rows of the file are the titles, and I would like to omit them. My command is below, but it outputs the original file without the first two rows, but also without sorting by the second column.

`awk -F ',' '(NR>2)’ filename.csv | sort -t',' -k2 -n`

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343720/how-to-split-a-csv-file-per-initial-column-with-headers

Comment: If you have a CSV file, ***post*** the CSV file. Table formatting is neat and keen, but please don’t use it inappropriately. Also, for questions about how to process data, show the input ***and*** the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant:

```
head -n 2 file.csv && tail -n +3 file.csv | sort -k 2
```

Just process title rows and data rows separately.

If you want to pass the result into something else, you can do parentheses:

```
(head -n 2 file.csv && tail -n +3 file.csv | sort -k 2) | less
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That command isn't sorting the second column for me. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It sorts rows by second column. Not the second column alone, if that is what you want.